# Is there a timeline for the Eugenic Wars?

Tags: star-trek

The Eugenics Wars are said to have occurred in the 1990s in “The Original Series” and “Wrath of Khan.” But “Voyager” visits our version of 1990s Los Angeles too, with no war or mention of genetically engineered super-men ruling significant portions of the planets.

How is this possible?  When did the wars actually happen?  Or were they erased from ever happening in some alternate  timeline?  Or are The Next Generation, Deep Space 9 And Voyager all in a timeline where it didn't happen?

Comment: According to the books, they weren't fought out in the open where any common citizens or the public knew about it. "They were shadowy conflicts fought behind the scenes of current events, against elusive and conspiratorial enemies whose genetically engineered origins remained largely unknown to the general public"  - http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Eugenics_Wars

Comment: That is a poor theory, considing that Spock said the Eugenics Wars were the last of Earth's world wars and that whole populations were being bombed out of existence.